# Next match without displaying Search String

Tags: string, search, vim, match

Sometimes I create a search string, by means of a function, that is very long, for example if there are a lot of matches.

If I press "n" to see the next match, I see this very long search string every time. 
Is it possible to use "n" and "N" without seeing the search string? 
(but I still want to see the other commands)

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the screen with

```
:redraw!
```

So, you could do this to not see your search string anymore:

```
nnoremap n n:redraw!<cr>
nnoremap N N:redraw!<cr>
```

Comment: Still the same search string. :(